# Remove hyphen when it's the last character

Tags: mysql

I have thousands of rows in a field where many of them contain `-` as the last character. I need to use the values as URL so these URLs are broken because of that. Could someone give me the SQL command for phpmyadmin to remove them without removing the other hyphens?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you are using MySQL... Because you didn't specify anything. This will probably port to other SQL versions as well though. In any case, interpret this as pseudo SQL code and you should get somewhere.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN RIGHT(My_Col, 1) = '-' THEN SUBSTR(My_Col, 0, LENGTH(My_Col)-2)
    ELSE My_Col AS My_Valid_Link
FROM
    My_Table
```

Comment: Yes it's mysql, I have wordpress installed. Just tryed SELECT
    CASE WHEN RIGHT(post_name, 1) = '-' THEN SUBSTR(post_name, 0, LENGTH(post_name)-2)
    ELSE post_name
FROM wp_posts  and I'm getting this error:  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM wp_posts LIMIT 0, 30' at line 4

Comment: What is the limit for? I just need to remove all hyphens when they are the last character in a value, in all rows without limit

Comment: I don't understand anything, is it impossible with this phpmyadmin version to remove - when its the last character or anything? Can someone give me the correct code please? Table name is wp_posts column name post_name

Comment: You did not do any work in advance and I gave you a place to start from. That is more than you can ask from the SO community. We do not do your work for you but we can give you a push if we see effort. I do not see any effort to understand on your part.

Comment: But I understand ZERO in this case

Comment: Well i tryed at least just to show fields with this case with SELECT wp_posts CASE WHEN RIGHT(post_name, 1) = '-' but nothing?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the SQL you need in case you use MySQL:

```
UPDATE your_table SET your_url = SUBSTR(your_url, 1, LENGTH(your_url) - 1) 
WHERE RIGHT(your_url, 1) = '-'
```

Explanation: RIGHT("https://www.example.com/bad-url-", 1) will equal "-".
We find all urls with hyphen at the end and replace the bad url with the same url but without the hyphen at the end (like @eatonphil post)

Warning: If `your_url` field has a unique key on it, it is possible that you will receive a duplicate key error.